# django rest framework: how to create yearly archive

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a yearly archive of all the posts in my blog and pass its as JSON to my app.

I am looking for something below.

```
[
  {
    year:2017
    url:
    numbrofposts: 100
    months: [
              {
               month: Jan
               numberofposts: 10
               url:
               listofposts: [
                               { id:, title,url}
                               { id:, title,url} 
                            ]
              }
            ]
  }
  {
    year:2016
    numbrofposts: 500
    months: [
              {
               month: Jan
               numberofposts: 30
               listofposts: [
                               { id:, title, description, etc}
                               { id:, title, description, etc} 
                            ]
              }
            ]
  }
...
]
```

If possible how to add pagination because the number of posts will keep increasing in future. I am not sure should the pagination be based on year or months

Assume i have a simple Posts model, with title and description and created_date

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reviewing the pagination guide: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

From that guide:

> Pagination is only performed automatically if you're using the generic views or viewsets. If you're using a regular APIView, you'll need to call into the pagination API yourself to ensure you return a paginated response. See the source code for the mixins.ListModelMixin and generics.GenericAPIView classes for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I am presently using for loop to create the JSON as below.

```
article_dict2 = []
months_names = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
for i in range(articles[0].publish_date.year, articles[len(articles)-1].publish_date.year-1, -1):
    #number of articles per year
    year_count = Article.objects.filter(publish_date__year=i).count()
    if year_count != 0:
        article_dict2_object = {}
        article_dict2_object['year'] = i
        article_dict2_object['total'] = year_count
        article_dict2_object['months'] = []
        for month in range(13,1,-1):
            #number of articles per month
            count = Article.objects.filter(publish_date__year=i,publish_date__month=month).count()
            if count != 0:
                month_object = {}
                month_object['mnum'] = month
                month_object['name'] = months_names[month-1]
                month_object['count'] = count
                month_object['articles'] = PostSerializerCalendar(Article.objects.filter(publish_date__year=i,publish_date__month=month),many=True).data
                article_dict2_object['months'].append(month_object)
return Response(article_dict2)
```

Is the above is effective way to query or there are better ways.

And I get the below results

```
[
    {
        "year": 2017,
        "total": 6,
        "months": [
            {
                "mnum": 10,
                "name": "October",
                "count": 1,
                "articles": [
                    {
                        "id": 58,
                        "title": "I, Me and Mine",
                        "publish_date": "2017-10-14 18:04 UTC",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "mnum": 8,
                "name": "August",
                "count": 5,
                "articles": [
                    {
                        "id": 57,
                        "title": "Youth, Manhood and Old-age",
                        "publish_date": "2017-08-09 12:30 UTC",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 56,
                        "title": "Enjoy the Eternal, not the Interval",
                        "publish_date": "2017-08-08 15:20 UTC",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 55,
                        "title": "Setting a Bad Example",
                        "publish_date": "2017-08-05 12:30 UTC",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 54,
                        "title": "Living a Long Life",
                        "publish_date": "2017-08-04 12:30 UTC",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 53,
                        "title": "Dying in the Dark",
                        "publish_date": "2017-08-03 14:34 UTC",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
   .......
]
```

I am not sure how to add pagination from which level year or month or posts. If i try for month or posts how to show the continuation in the next page

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class LargeResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10  #no of pages
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 10
```

**views.py**

```
dataoforpost=models.objects.all()
paginator = LargeResultsSetPagination()
page = paginator.paginate_queryset(dataoforpost, request)
response = paginator.get_paginated_response(page)
return response
```